# Magento 2 Admin- Invalid data provided for linked products

Tags: php, magento, admin, magento2

Getting an error:

> "Invalid data provided for linked products"

when adding related products to a product from the admin panel and saving

Indexer crons, already setup

Magento CLI version is : 2.1.1

How can I fix it or use database to add the related products?

I have imported products from Magento 1.9 using the magento data-migration-tool

Also getting error in the admin panel if I move a category from one parent to another, I have to go to database to make the change for that.